# 'provided' dependency not found R class

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two Android libs in my workspace. I'm trying to include the lib A as a dependency of the lib B but using the tag 'compile' gradle runs the compile tasks for all its builds. Now I'm trying using the tag 'provided' but in the lib B I want to use the class R of the lib A, which is not found. Any help or suggestion?